# How to access to sub related model when the related model returns a collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 models: User, Payment and Log. A User has many Payment and both User and Payment have many Log.

**User Model**

```
class User
{

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Payment', 'user_id');
    }

    public function logs()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Log::class, 'loggable');
    }

}
```

**users table**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `email_verified_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Payment Model**

```
class Payment
{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function logs()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Log::class, 'loggable');
    }

}
```

**payments table**

```
CREATE TABLE `payments` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `status` varchar(50),
    `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `collection_date` date NOT NULL,
    `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_payments_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Log Model**

```
class Log
{
    public function loggable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}
```

**logs table**

```
CREATE TABLE `logs` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `loggable_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `loggable_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `old_values` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `new_values` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, /* the user that made the change, if any */
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The Log model stores all changes made to any other model (it's a polymorphic relationship), so if the user changes its name, the Log model will store the older name and the new name. The same applies to Payment: if a payment status changes the Log model will have a new record with the old status and the new status.

I need to show a paginated list of all Log records for a specific User ordered by date. So my code is:

```
$user = App\User::find($id);
$allLogs = $user->logs();

// Now I need to join (I'm using union) both sets of logs
$allLogs->union($user->payments->logs());
```

However, since a User can have many Payment, `$user->payments` returns a Collection, so is no longer a query builder/eloquent object and it fails when I try to call `->logs()`.

`$user->payments()->logs()` also doesn't work, because `$user->payments()` returns a `HasMany` object and the `->logs()` method doesn't exist.

I'm trying to avoid getting each collection of `Log` separately and then processing them using php (it would be perfect to delegate that task to MySql).

I believe it can be done, because I can write the query on MySql:

```
select l.*
from payments p
join logs l on p.id = l.loggable_id and l.loggable_type = 'App\\Payments'
where p.user_id = SOMEUSERID
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add the structure of these tables so we can see the keys and how the relationships are setup

Comment: @lagbox, thanks for your reply. I've just added the sql code and the models

Answer (score 0):

Eager load the relations(reduces number of queries)

```
$user = User::with(['payments.logs', 'logs'])->find($id);
```

Query using the Log model.

```
$logs = Log::where([
       'loggable_id' =>  $user->id,
       'loggable_type' => 'User',
     ])
     ->orWhere(function($query){
           $query->whereIn('loggable_id', 
                     $user->payments()->pluck('id'))
                 ->where('loggable_type', 'Payment');
     })->get();
```

OR

Get them individually and then combine them.

```
$all_logs = collect([]);

$all_logs->push($user->logs);

foreach($user->payments as $p){
    $all_logs->push($p->logs);
}


$final_logs = $all_logs->collapse();
```

OR

Just use the relations, without iterating over the payments. You can combine the results if you want(as shown in the previous approach).

```
$user_logs = $user->logs;

$payment_logs = $user->payments->pluck('logs')->collapse();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply @Aashish gaba. Is there any way to accomplish the same using relationships? Thanks

Comment: Yes, but then you'll have to iterate over the payments and get log from each payment.

Comment: I've updated the answer, now it contains both the ways :)

Comment: but in this second way you are getting all records and then combining them using php. Is there a way to get the payment logs via SQL? (i want to avoid processing the logs in php)

Comment: If you want to use relation then you'll have to iterate over payments. Otherwise the solution contains the way using Log Model using which you can get combined logs for both, isn't it what you exactly needed ?

Comment: @TJistooshort I've updated the answer, and now you won't have to iterate over the records, you can do it by using methods that collection supports. If the answer solves your problem, upvote to the answer is desirable. Thanks :)